# How do I filter QTableView with QSortFilterProxyModel using checked items AND text?

Tags: pyqt6

I'm working with TableViews in a Stacked Layout. The parent widget contains form controls (a lineEdit and a master checkbox) which manipulate the filters of the tableviews.

The master checkbox needs to be able to hide every checked item in the visible model.

How do I filter based on the CheckStateRole instead of the DisplayRole? In the code below, the third line from the bottom you will see a "what do I do here?", which is where I've lost the ability to understand any more of the documentation without concrete examples.

Current code:

```py
class ShippingWindow(QWidget, Ui_shippingWidget):
    def __init__(self, saveData, objectData, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.saveData = saveData
        self.objectData = objectData
        # set up our stacked layout. shipWidget, polyWidget and monoWidget will hold our tables.
        self.stackedLayout = QStackedLayout()
        self.shipWidget = QTableView()
        self.shipModel = QStandardItemModel()
        self.stackedLayout.addWidget(self.shipWidget)
        self.stackWidget = QWidget()
        self.stackWidget.setLayout(self.stackedLayout)
        self.stackedLayout.setCurrentWidget(self.shipWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.stackWidget)
        # setup our contents
        self.populateShipping(saveData, objectData)
        # Attach the line edit to the Filter.
        self.filterTable.textChanged.connect(self.shippingFilterProxy.setFilterRegularExpression)
        # radio button logic for swapping currentWidget
        self.radioShip.toggled.connect(self.toggleShip)
        self.radioPoly.toggled.connect(self.togglePoly)
        self.radioMono.toggled.connect(self.toggleMono)
        # hide shipped checkbox logic
        self.hideShipped.stateChanged.connect(self.toggleShippedItems)

    def populateShipping(self, saveData, objectData):
        shippingBox = self.shipWidget
        excludedCats = ["Moved", "Tax-Exempt"]
        shippables = list(filter(None, [value if "SendOnly" in value and "FullShipment" in value["SendOnly"] and value["SendOnly"]["FullShipment"] and value["Category"] not in excludedCats else '' for value in objectData]))
        # sort by name
        sorted_shippables = sorted(shippables, key=lambda d: d["Name"])
        self.shipModel = QStandardItemModel(len(sorted_shippables), 5)
        self.shipModel.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Item", "Category", "Price", "Sources", "Developer"])
        shippingBox.verticalHeader().hide()
        # self.shipModel.setRowCount(len(shippables))
        row = 0
        for item in sorted_shippables:
            itemObj = SVObject(**item)
            nameCell = QStandardItem(itemObj.Name)
            nameCell.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEnabled)
            if itemObj.ID["objects"] in saveData["basicShipped"]:
                nameCell.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Checked)
            else:
                nameCell.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Unchecked)
            priceCell = QStandardItem()
            priceCell.setData(itemObj.Price, QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole)
            itemSources = list(item["Sources"].keys())
            sourceString = ", ".join(itemSources)
            sourceCell = QStandardItem(sourceString)
            self.shipModel.setItem(row, 0, nameCell)
            self.shipModel.setItem(row, 1, QStandardItem(itemObj.Category))
            self.shipModel.setItem(row, 2, priceCell)
            self.shipModel.setItem(row, 3, sourceCell)
            self.shipModel.setItem(row, 4, QStandardItem(itemObj.ModName))
            row += 1
        shippingBox.setSortingEnabled(True)
        # set up the filter proxy model
        self.shippingFilterProxy = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.shippingFilterProxy.setSourceModel(self.shipModel)
        self.shippingFilterProxy.setFilterKeyColumn(0)
        self.shippingFilterProxy.setFilterRole(QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole)
        self.shippingFilterProxy.setFilterCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive)
        self.shipWidget.setModel(self.shippingFilterProxy)
        shippingBox.resizeColumnsToContents()

    def toggleShippedItems(self, s):
        if s == 2:
            if self.stackedLayout.currentIndex() == 0:
                # change the role to checkstate for a moment
                self.shippingFilterProxy.setFilterRole(QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.CheckStateRole)
                self.shippingFilterProxy.setFilterFixedString(2)   # what do I do here?
                # change the role back so the text filter works again?
                # self.shippingFilterProxy.setFilterRole(QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole)
```

Where I'm stuck is in toggleShippedItems at the very end. I've tried looping the models, they are non-iterable. I need to be able hide the checked items, keep them hidden, and still have the lineEdit search remain in effect. I'm much more comfortable with TableWidget, but since I need the text filter, I'm floundering out of my depth with TableView.

Comment: Sorry but your question is very confusing. Most of it is unrelated to what you want to know: the QStackedLayout part is completely irrelevant to the filtering problem (especially considering that you're focusing on *one* view). Besides, there's really no point in using QStackedLayout in QWidget unless custom behavior is needed: use QStackedWidget instead. If your question is about filtering items based on multiple aspects, then just ask about that: you need a QSortFilterProxyModel subclass for it, overriding [`filterAcceptsRow()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#filterAcceptsRow).

Comment: I mentioned the QStackedLayout because the same form controls must be reused to every layer of the stack. Sorry if that is confusing to you. I am uncertain if that detail will affect the advice provided as I've been using PyQt for less than a week.

As stated in the title, I need to know how configure the filter the tableview based on checkstate of the items in column 0. The third line from the bottom of the code where it says "What to I do here?" is where I am stuck.

I do not know what you mean by `filterAcceptsRow()`.

Comment: I specifically linked the documentation about `filterAcceptsRows()`. If you want to change the default filtering behavior of QSortFilterProxyModel, overriding that function is one way. Everything is explained in the class documentation, so please take your time to carefully study it.

Comment: I have read what you linked. I have also searched every corner of the internet for usage examples of how it is applied to CheckStateRole. Every usage example uses DIsplayRole. I can find no dox on CheckStateRole at all. The PyQt documentation is completely incomprehensible to me as it's so completely abstracted. I think instead I will add a hidden column with a "true" text for checked rows and then filter based on the text since I know how to do that already.

Comment: Don't use PyQt docs, they are fundamentally useless except for the few exceptions about different function signatures or returned types (note that this is also valid for the "Qt for Python"/PySide docs, which are fundamentally copies of the C++ ones). The concept behind `filterAcceptsRows()` is the same no matter the role: just check against the source index `data(Qt.CheckStateRole)` instead, and return `True`/`False` based on your needs. If you don't understand the meaning of roles, please take your time to study the [Model/View Programming docs](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html).

Comment: Really, don't use a hidden column for that, there's no point, and it's based on the wrong reason for your case. You already have access to the check state, then you need to check *that* state, **not** the displayed value, which is a different role with a different purpose. Don't try to work around a problem (in the wrong way) just because you don't understand its underlying aspects: try to understand those aspects first, and eventually ask a *specific* question about them. If those problems cannot be solved, *then* we can try to find *proper* work arounds.

Comment: At this point I've given up on working with the CheckStateRole due to lack of specific documentation on it. I'll revisit it in a week or two when I'm not so frustrated with it. Thanks for the help provided and the insults offered but I will run with the kludgey text search on hidden column for now. I know the PyQt docs are very poorly done but they're all I've got for learning this framework. I can't even figure out how to run introspection on these classes so I'm clinging to the docs like a life preserver.

Comment: The PyQt docs are not "poorly done": they *are* poorly maintained, but that's because it would be fundamentally pointless to really care about them, since they would just be a copy of the C++ docs (interestingly enough, that's also why most of the PySide docs are useless and misleading). If you want to study the documentation about Qt, you *must* use the C++ docs as primary source, which wouldn't be that different from a possible "well written" Python/Qt documentation. Qt is an extremely powerful and extended toolkit, it may take *months* to begin to really understand it. Be patient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those searching in the future, here is how I resolved the question on my own. It's cobbled together from PyQt4 and PyQt5 snippets updated to PyQt6, and C++ versions run through an automated C++ to Python translator.

New populateShipping method:

```py
    def populateShipping(self, saveData, objectData):
        shippingBox = self.shipWidget
        shippingBox.setStyleSheet("border: 5px ridge rgb(91, 43, 42);")

        excludedCats = ["Moved", "Tax-Exempt"]
        shippables = list(filter(None, [value if "SendOnly" in value and "FullShipment" in value["SendOnly"] and value["SendOnly"]["FullShipment"] and value["Category"] not in excludedCats else '' for value in objectData]))
        # sort by name
        sorted_shippables = sorted(shippables, key=lambda d: d["Name"])
        dataTable = []
        for item in sorted_shippables:
            dataRow = []
            # populate the dataTable here, snip snip
            dataTable.append(dataRow)
        labels = ["Name", "Category", "Price", "Sources", "Developer"]

        # set up the model and proxies
        self.shippingmodel = ShippablesTableModel(dataTable, labels)

        # check the boxes for any shipped items
        checkCol = 0
        for r in range(self.shippingmodel.rowCount()):
            itemID = sorted_shippables[r]["ID"]["objects"]
            checkIdx = self.shippingmodel.index(r, checkCol)
            if str(itemID) in self.saveData["basicShipped"]:
                self.shippingmodel.setData(checkIdx, QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Checked, QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.CheckStateRole)

        # checkbox proxy filter
        self.shippedProxyModel = ShippingCheckProxy()
        self.shippedProxyModel.setSourceModel(self.shippingmodel)
        self.shippedProxyModel.setFilterFixedString("All")

        # search box proxy filter nests checkbox proxy filter
        self.shippeditemNameProxyModel = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.shippeditemNameProxyModel.setSourceModel(self.shippedProxyModel)
        self.shippeditemNameProxyModel.setFilterKeyColumn(0)
        self.shippeditemNameProxyModel.setFilterCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive)

        # populate and design the actual table.
        shippingBox.setSortingEnabled(True)
        shippingBox.setModel(self.shippeditemNameProxyModel)
        shippingBox.verticalHeader().hide()
        shippingBox.horizontalHeader().setStyleSheet("border: none;")
        shippingBox.resizeColumnsToContents()
```

Custom Table Model:

```py
class ShippablesTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, shippingData, headerNames, parent=None):
        super(ShippablesTableModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.tableData = shippingData
        self.columnNames = headerNames
        self.checks = {}

    def columnCount(self, *args):
        return len(self.columnNames)

    def rowCount(self, *args):
        return len(self.tableData)

    def checkState(self, index):
        if index in self.checks.keys():
            return self.checks[index]
        else:
            return QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Unchecked

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole):
        row = index.row()
        col = index.column()
        if role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            value = self.tableData[row][col]
            return value
        elif role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.CheckStateRole and col == 0:
            return self.checkState(QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(index))
        return None

    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return False
        if role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.CheckStateRole:
            self.checks[QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(index)] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return True
        return False

    def flags(self, index):
        fl = QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.flags(self, index)
        if index.column() == 0:
            fl = QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEnabled
        return fl

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole and orientation == QtCore.Qt.Orientation.Horizontal:
            return self.columnNames[col]
        return None
```

Custom QSortFilterProxyModel:

```py
class ShippingCheckProxy(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ShippingCheckProxy, self).__init__(parent)

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, row_num, parent):
        model = self.sourceModel()
        shippedIdx = model.index(row_num, 0, parent)
        thisState = shippedIdx.data(QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.CheckStateRole)
        # we can only pass a regex through, but we only want the actual text 
        # (pattern), not a parsed regex.
        regex = self.filterRegularExpression()
        pattern = regex.pattern()
        # If the 0 pattern is submitted, only show rows with unchecked boxes.
        if pattern == "0":
            if thisState == QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Unchecked or thisState == 0:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        # otherwise show everything.
        return True
```